# Can one player win more games while scoring fewer points over multiple trials a simple probabilistic game?

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory

### The Game

Two players $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ will play the following game:

1. Three non-negative numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ will be selected at random from a distribution unknown to either player. The players know only that the numbers will be non-negative.
2. Player $P_{1}$ will be given a choice of two options, after they make their selection the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ will be revealed, and $P_1$ and $P_2$ will score points depending on the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ as described below. ($P_2$ makes no choices.)
3. Player $P_{1}$'s two options are:

   - Option 1: Score points equal to $a+b$.
   - Option 2: Score points equal to the maximum value of $a$, $b$, or $c$.

   Note: Neither player knows the values of $a$, $b$, or $c$ at the time this choice is made.
4. Whichever option $P_{1}$ selects, $P_{2}$ will score the points of the other unselected option.
   For example, if:

   - $P_1$ selects Option 2
   - $a$, $b$, and $c$ turn out to be $1$, $17$, and $\pi$ respectively

   Then:

   - $P_1$ scores $17$ points (e.g. the maximum of $1$, $17$, and $\pi$)
   - $P_2$ scores $18$ points (e.g. $a+b = 1+17 = 18$)
5. The player who scores the most points wins the game. (Ties are also possible.)

### The Scenario

Let's assume:

- The game will be played some number $N$ times, with the unknown distribution from which $a$, $b$, and $c$ are selected remaining fixed over these $N$ games.
- $P_1$ must select the same choice of Option 1 or 2 in each of the $N$ games. (e.g. they make only one choice at the beginning of Option 1 or 2, which is then applied in every game.)
- We tabulate both:

  - The number of times each player wins
  - The cumulative points scored by each player over the $N$ games

### The Question

1. Does there exist:

   - A distribution of numbers from which $a$, $b$, and $c$ are selected
   - A choice by $P_1$, and
   - Sufficiently large $N$

Such that both:

- $P_1$ is expected to win at least as many games as $P_2$, and
- $P_1$ is also expected to score no more points than $P_2$

? (Thanks to Marcus M for answering this with a clear example!)

2. Does the answer change if all values must be positive, as opposed to non-zero?

My **sense** is that there is **no such distribution possible** when $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive - but I'm not sure **how to go about proving that**?

It's fairly easy to construct distributions such that Option 1 or Option 2 **both** lead to $P_1$ expecting to **win more games and scoring more points**, for example:

- If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are always some permutation of 0, 0, and 1 then as $N$ approaches infinity:

  - Option 2 ties 2 games out of 3 and wins 1 game out of 3
  - Option 2 scores 1 point per game whereas Option 1 expects to score $2/3$ points per game
- If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are selected over a uniform continuous distribution then as $N$ approaches infinity:

  - Option 1 expects to win 5 games out of 6, and score $4/3$rds as many points as Option 2.

However I'm interested if it's possible to have distribution where there is a split outcome of winning more while also scoring less overall.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is indeed possible and the following distribution does it.  Consider $a, b$ and $c$ are a permutation of $0, 1$ and $10$, with every permutation chosen with equal probability.  If $P_1$ always chooses $a + b$, then the possibilities (with equal probability) are

- $c = 0,~a + b = 11$: $P_1$ scores $11$, $P_2$ scores $10$.
- $c = 1,~a + b = 10$: $P_1$ scores $10$, $P_2$ scores $10$.
- $c = 10,~a + b = 1$: $P_1$ scores $1$, $P_2$ scores $10$.

Then $P_1$ wins the first case, ties the second case, and loses in the third case, meaning that $P_1$ wins exactly as often as $P_2$.  However, $P_1$'s expected score - $P_2$'s expected score is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 0 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot (-9) = \frac{-8}{3} < 0$.   Thus $P_1$ has the same expected number of wins as $P_2$, but has a lower expected score than $P_2$.

Comment: True enough!  I wonder if there is a distribution that holds as well when all the values must be positive.

Comment: All the values here are positive; the $\frac{-8}{3}$ is $P_1$'s expected score minus $P_2$'s expected score.  This means that $P_1$ has a lower expected score than $P_2$.

Comment: I meant if all values of a, b, and c must be greater than zero.